# numbering error in the sections heading

Tags: sectioning

The numbering in different sections is showing like 0.1, 0.2 instead of 1, 2 ....
What should I do to correct  this, my code is as :

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{report}
\usepackage[left= 12 mm,top=1 in,bottom=2 in ]{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper}

\begin{document}
\title{chapter1}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
```

Comment: `\title` is the document title not for chapters etc.

Comment: `12mm` for left margin is very small, actually

Answer (score 2):

You start with `\section` and it is counted as `chapter.section`. But you have no chapter defined, so it uses `0.1`. Use the `article` class instead or define a `\chapter{...}` before using `\section{...}`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is wanted if `report` is used, the sectioning level hierarchy is (starting from top)

`\part`

`\chapter`

`\section`

`\subsection`

`\subsubsection`

`\paragraph`

`\subparagraph`

In my point of view `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` should not be used, since that levelling is too deep.

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{report}
\usepackage[left= 12 mm,top=1 in,bottom=2 in ]{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper}

\begin{document}
\title{My nice document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Some text}

\subsection{some minor text}

\chapter{Even more content in here}

\end{document}
```